# Ubuntu 20.4 Asus Tuf Dash F15 Can't Install Nvidia Driver

Tags: installation, gpu, driver, nvidia

I have installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 20.4 on my band new Asus Tuf Dash F15 laptop. Then I went into the software update settings and switched the driver to nvidia-460 proprietary using the GUI. I apply the changes and restart and I get stuck at a boot loading screen. The error is /dev/nvm1e0 clean: xxxblocks/xxx.

Specs: Nvidia RTX 36060 mobile Intel i7 40gb ram 1tb storage

I have tried installing the nvidia drivers 4 different ways, according to the nvidia official installation guide and multiple medium forums. Every time I get the same problem and have to alt+shift+f2 my way into the terminal to sudo apt-get purge nvidia* to be able to boot back in.

I've installed nvidia diver on ubuntu many other times according to the nvidia official docs and never ran into this error. I am concerned it may be hardware incompatibility at this point?

I've been trying for five days now and re-installed ubuntu multiple times, varying the partitions and installation methods. Everything is working fine until I try and switch to nvidia driver. I even tried some older and new driver versions and the nvidia cuda toolkit 10 and 11. Please help, thank you.